# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException Error in Marshmallow only, but working properly in Nougat

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException Error in Android M only ,working proper in Android N.When i remove vectore drable file its work fine

```
  android {

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.h8.subscriber"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    generatedDensities = []
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig getSigningConfig()
    }
}

aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}


}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i 'm using Vector Drawable Gradients.thiis is working in Android  N but not working in Android M

Answer (score 1):

Well I had the same problem. The image resource was not working on Marshmallow.

My problem was that the image was actually in drawable-v24, and not in drawable folder.

U can also check with this. if the image is in v24 it will be shown in the resource folder(underlined with red in the image provided).

Change it from v24 to the normal drawable folder and you are **done**.

[image]